# How to create a custom Azure Function input binding which parses a route parameter

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I've been trying to create an Azure input binding which will parse a *route* (not query) parameter.

For example, I want to use the following route: `api/collections/(db105773-e804-4d93-8f84-5c3a9c9cea05,db105773-e804-4d93-8f84-5c3a9c9cea05)`.

The idea then is to have the input binding parse that last segment `(db105773-e804-4d93-8f84-5c3a9c9cea05,db105773-e804-4d93-8f84-5c3a9c9cea05)` of the route and pass those values as an `IEnumerable<Guid>` to the Azure function as a parameter.

I've gotten close, but still no cigar. I keep getting the following error when I attempt to call the function:

> Exception binding parameter 'ids'. System.Private.CoreLib: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Guid, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]

Currently, this is what I have thus far (sorry for the amount of code here but there are a lot of moving parts to creating a custom binding).

##### Attribute

```
[Binding]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class FromRouteCollectionAttribute : Attribute 
{
    [AutoResolve]
    public string? Items { get; set; }
}
```

##### Binding type filter

```
public class FromRouteCollectionBindingType : OpenType.Poco
{
    public override bool IsMatch(Type type, OpenTypeMatchContext context)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            return true;

        return base.IsMatch(type, context);
    }
}
```

##### Converter

```
public class FromRouteCollectionConverter : IConverter<FromRouteCollectionAttribute, IEnumerable<Guid>>
{
    private static readonly Regex _pattern = 
        new(@"^\((?<collection>.*)\)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public IEnumerable<Guid> Convert(FromRouteCollectionAttribute input)
    {
        var match = _pattern.Match(input?.Items ?? string.Empty);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            var group = match.Groups["collection"];
            var split = group.Value.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            return split.Select(Guid.Parse).ToList();
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<Guid>().ToList();
    }
}
```

##### Configuration provider

```
[Extension("FromRouteCollection")]
public class FromRouteCollectionConfigProvider : IExtensionConfigProvider
{
    public void Initialize(ExtensionConfigContext context)
    {     
        var rule = context.AddBindingRule<FromRouteCollectionAttribute>();
        rule.BindToInput<FromRouteCollectionBindingType>(typeof(FromRouteCollectionConverter));        
    }
}
```

##### Registration

```
internal class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var webBuilder = builder.Services.AddWebJobs(_ => { return; });
        webBuilder.AddExtension<FromRouteCollectionConfigProvider>();
    }
}
```

##### Azure Function

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCollection(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "collections/{ids}")] 
        HttpRequest req,
        [FromRouteCollection(Items = "{ids}")]
        IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

What's interesting here is if I change the type of the `ids` parameter of the Azure function to `object` and then change the output type of the `IConverter` `interface` to `object` and lastly change the `FromRouteCollectionBindingType` to `return` `true` when the Azure function argument is of type `object`, then everything works. I get an `object` passed to my Azure function which can be casted to an `IEnumerable<Guid>` which contains the route parameters. Of course that's a suboptimal solution.

I feel like I'm missing a piece here but I'm unsure what that is, any help would be appreciated.

As a side note, I'm not interested is passing this via a query string nor the request body.